# In MoveIt where is the namespace of the follow_joint_trajectory defined?

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-melodic, universal-robots

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having maybe a silly problem.

I define a MoveIt package for my UR3e robot for Gazebo simulation and it works fine. I define the controllers in simulation as `leftarm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory`. However, now I am trying to set up the same MoveIt package for the real robot and the controller is loaded as `scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller/follow_joint_trajectory` so I get the error:

```
[ WARN]: Waiting for leftarm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory to come up
[ERROR]: Action client not connected: leftarm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory
```

I checked all the moveit files of my package and couldn't figure out where is the move_group getting the follow_joint_trajectory namespace from.

I am using a workaround with the **remap** tag in the move_group as:

> `<remap if="$(arg real_robot)" from="leftarm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory" to="scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller/follow_joint_trajectory"/>`

But I would really want to know where is the name of the controller defined.

Edit: This is [my repository](https://github.com/cambel/dual_ur3e) with the configuration that I am currently using with the workaround.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371563/in-moveit-where-is-the-namespace-of-the-follow_joint_trajectory-defined?/) by [cambel07](https://answers.ros.org/users/50158/cambel07/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2021-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is best practice to make your Gazebo package publish its controllers under the same name as your real robot. Your simulation is much easier to change than the real robot driver.

Your `leftarm_controller` is probably defined in the `controllers.yaml` of your gazebo package. Change `leftarm_controller` to say `scaled_pos_joint_trajectory` and make sure the type of controller matches. You can find the type of controller in your robot's driver package (in your case it is `position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController`).

If you have multiple robot arms, you will want to start your robot driver in a namespace, so it advertises on different topics than the other arm. In that case its controller action will be at e.g. `left_arm/scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller/follow_joint_trajectory`. You can reproduce this in your gazebo package's `controllers.yaml` by nesting the tags:

```
left_arm:
  scaled_pos_joint_trajectory_controller:
    type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
...
```

An easy way to solve this problem would have been to search for `leftarm_controller` in your workspace until you find the `yaml` file it is defined in. `Ctrl+Shift+F` searches through your workspace in Visual Studio Code, for example.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2021-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cambel07](https://answers.ros.org/users/50158/cambel07/) on 2021-02-11**:
That's exactly the problem, I did search for the definition of my leftarm_controller. But I couldn't find it other than in the `ros_controllers.yaml` file. However, even if I modify the `moveit package/ros_controllers.yaml` to have match the expected `left_arm/scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller/follow_joint_trajectory`it did not work. I also try removing any loading of the controllers configuration file in the `move_group` and other configuration files, but it somehow keeps expecting the `leftarm_controller` from somewhere.

I will try to create the package from zero where I use the expected controller namespace from gazebo too.

For now, I just finished uploading a working [Github repository](https://github.com/cambel/dual_ur3e) with my current approach

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-02-11**:
You are launching a controller with the name `leftarm_controller` [here](https://github.com/cambel/dual_ur3e/blob/main/ur3e_dual_gazebo/launch/dual_ur3e.launch#L44), and your MoveIt node is told to look for that name [here](https://github.com/cambel/dual_ur3e/blob/main/ur3e_dual_moveit_config/config/dual_ur3e_controllers.yaml). If you change the name in the latter file to `/left_arm/scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller` and launch the robot driver in the `left_arm` namespace, it should work.

**Comment by [cambel07](https://answers.ros.org/users/50158/cambel07/) on 2021-02-11**:
Yes, but the first one is for the simulation only so it doesn't affect the setup for the real robot. The second one is also never loaded with starting moveit for the real robots [here](https://github.com/cambel/dual_ur3e/blob/main/ur3e_dual_moveit_config/launch/start_real_dual_ur3e_moveit.launch)
The only controller config file that I can see that is being loaded is [this](https://github.com/cambel/dual_ur3e/blob/main/ur3e_dual_moveit_config/config/ros_controllers.yaml) from this [launch file](https://github.com/cambel/dual_ur3e/blob/main/ur3e_dual_moveit_config/launch/ur3e_moveit_controller_manager.launch.xml). But as I mentioned above, even when I update that config file to use the real robot controllers namespace it just doesn't seem to work. It somehow seems to be still expecting to get the `leftarm_controller`

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-02-12**:
MoveIt expects the controller listed in `ros_controllers.yaml`, so that should be correct. Try uploading the version that you expect to work to that repository and linking the commit.

**Comment by [cambel07](https://answers.ros.org/users/50158/cambel07/) on 2021-02-12**:
Thanks for the patience, I'm sure [this](https://github.com/cambel/dual_ur3e/commit/200fe0e1ac5425d9abf050a8611b1c3011a6c5fa) is what I tried yesterday. But I will test it again next week.

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-02-12**:
Looks right to me. Could be a simple mixup from something else (forgot to save, forgot to restart, wrong workspace etc.)

**Comment by [cambel07](https://answers.ros.org/users/50158/cambel07/) on 2021-02-14**:
Well it seems that I made some mistake before or there was indeed some lingering memory of the namespace somewhere. After restarting and testing the version without the workaround it worked just fine. Thanks!

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2021-02-14**:
Great. Restarting `roscore` is a good idea in these situations, to reset the parameter server.